# How can I modify the DLL references of a program which I do not have the source code for?

Tags: windows, dll

So there is an executable, `foo.exe`. Other executables around it in the same directory depend on `bar.dll`, version 2. But `foo.exe` depends on `bar.dll`, version **1**.

Let's say I rename `bar.dll`, version 1 to `bar1.dll`. Version 2 is still called `bar.dll`.

So is it possible for me to somehow modify the binary `foo.exe` to load `bar1.dll` instead of `bar.dll`?

Comment: Can it work? Sure it might work, if it will work, will entirely depend on the differences between the two versions of the the dynamic library.

Comment: Have you tried renaming *bar1.dll* to *bar.dll*? Might work, or not, but easier than modifying the executable!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik But you see, version 1 and 2 have the same names and are needed by programs depending on different versions in the same directory. My question is asking if it's possible to rename version 1 and change references to the version 1 DLL. (I am aware of which programs use v1 and which use v2.)

Comment: it depends on how the versions are different. IIRC as long as no methods are added/removed, and all the method signatures are identical, then the existing entry points will remain at the same addresses. if not, you have to recompile from source. as an example i like modding Bethesda games, but every time a new version of the exe is released, a new version of the script extender dlls must be recompiled against it, and most mods that rely on the script extender need to be re-released as well.  its a real pain...

Comment: A function called `__crc32_encrypt` or something like that was removed from Version 2 and readded inside the program itself so no, the two DLLs are not cross-compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two DLL versions are compatible on entry-point names and
arguments, you don't need to modify anything.
You only need to use the DLL
loading order rules of Windows, which gives priority to loading
DLLs from the folder where the executive is located.

You then need to isolate each application in its own folder,
duplicating common files in both folders (if required),
or perhaps adding in one folder only symbolic links to files
in the other folder (to avoid duplication).

The folder for each app should contain its own version for the DLL,
using the right name.

This way, there are no conflicts, and you don't need to hex-edit
the app's executable.

---

If entry-points are different as regarding names and/or arguments,
you will need to program your own interface DLL and call it
`bar.dll`. The old DLL can be renamed and called from your
newly-written DLL.

To help in analyzing the entry-points of the two versions and
compare entry points and arguments, see the post
[How to generate an import library (LIB-file) from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946322/how-to-generate-an-import-library-lib-file-from-a-dll)

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question, the author wants to load a specific version of the library, one that might not be compatible with the application that will use it.  Can the author place the library in the executable directory, of course they can, that does not mean it will work the way they want.

Comment: @Ramhound That is correct. Though, I can't help but upvote this answer since it does make sense, it's just that it's not applicable in my case.

Comment: @HackerDaGreat57: I have added more info about what to do in case the entry-points have changed between the two versions. This requires some programming knowledge.

Comment: @harrymc Ok thanks 